# Сортировка двух массивов по одному значению, их вывод в ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, ng-repeat

Доброго времени суток.
Хочу отсортировать 2 массива по одному значению - pubdate. Вчера мне подсказали, как отсортировать таким образом 1 массив, по примеру, я сделал такое:

```
$scope.items = data.articles.concat(data.posts);
 $scope.items.sort(function(a, b) {
   return b.pubdate - a.pubdate;
  });
```

Всё вроде бы сортируется так, как мне нужно. Но возникла теперь проблема с выводом этого массива. Я не знаю, как правильно его вывести.
У меня 2 типа публикаций - небольшой текст и статья. Нужно вывести и то, и то, но с сортировкой по дате(pubdate). Делал так:

```
<div class="post-wrapper" ng-repeat="item in items | startFrom: startingItem() | limitTo: itemsPerPage | orderBy:'-pubdate'">
    <p class="pubdate">{{ item.pubdate * 1000 | date:'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mma'}}</p>
    <p class="post-text">{{ item.text }}</p>
    <p class="post-text">{{ item.article }}</p>
  </div>
```

Но работает не так, я предполагал, и я, в принципе, знаю почему. Но, увы, не знаю, как правильно сделать.
JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/83jt342x/

```js
var app = angular.module('app', [])
  .filter('startFrom', function() {
    return function(input, start) {
      start = +start;
      return input.slice(start);
    }
  })
  .controller('paginationCtrl', function($scope, $http) {
    $http({
      method: 'GET',
      url: 'https://api.myjson.com/bins/4iqg2'
    }).success(function(data) {
      $scope.items = data.articles.concat(data.posts);
      $scope.items.sort(function(a, b) {
        return b.pubdate - a.pubdate;
      });
    });

    $scope.currentPage = 0;
    $scope.itemsPerPage = 3;
    $scope.firstPage = function() {
      return $scope.currentPage == 0;
    }
    $scope.lastPage = function() {
      var lastPageNum = Math.ceil($scope.items.length / $scope.itemsPerPage - 1);
      return $scope.currentPage == lastPageNum;
    }
    $scope.numberOfPages = function() {
      return Math.ceil($scope.items.length / $scope.itemsPerPage);
    }
    $scope.startingItem = function() {
      return $scope.currentPage * $scope.itemsPerPage;
    }
    $scope.pageBack = function() {
      $scope.currentPage = $scope.currentPage - 1;
    }
    $scope.pageForward = function() {
      $scope.currentPage = $scope.currentPage + 1;
    }
  });
```

```css
.wrapper {
  position: relative;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border-left: 1px solid #141516;
  border-right: 1px solid #141516;
  background: rgba(50, 50, 50, .3);
  overflow: hidden;
}

.post-wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 400px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
}

.pubdate {
  width: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  font-size: 15px;
  font-family: monospace;
  text-align: center;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #323232;
  color: #323232;
}

.post-text {
  font-size: 25px;
  color: #141414;
  padding: 15px;
  background: rgba(50, 50, 50, 0.1);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

.pagination {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="wrapper" ng-app="app" ng-controller="paginationCtrl">
  <div class="post-wrapper" ng-repeat="item in items | startFrom: startingItem() | limitTo: itemsPerPage | orderBy:'-pubdate'">
    <p class="pubdate">{{ item.pubdate * 1000 | date:'MM/dd/yyyy hh:mma'}}</p>
    <p class="post-text">{{ item.text }}</p>
    <p class="post-text">{{ item.article }}</p>
  </div>
  <div class="pagination text-center">
    <button class="pull-left btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-disabled="firstPage()" ng-click="pageBack()">Prev page</button>
    <span class="page-num">{{currentPage+1}} of {{numberOfPages()}}</span>
    <button class="pull-right btn btn-primary btn-sm" ng-disabled="lastPage()" ng-click="pageForward()">Next page</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

JSON: https://api.myjson.com/bins/4iqg2

```
{
    "articles":[
        {"pubdate":1461495344,"article":"AText 1"},         
        {"pubdate":1461492824,"article":"AText 2"},
        {"pubdate":1461482024,"article":"AText 3"},
        {"pubdate":1461486944,"article":"AText 4"}
    ],
    "posts":[
        {"pubdate":1461431721,"text":"Text1"},
        {"pubdate":1461431781,"text":"Text2"},
        {"pubdate":1461431901,"text":"Text3"},
        {"pubdate":1461431961,"text":"Text4"},
        {"pubdate":1461432021,"text":"Text5"}
    ]
}
```

P.S. Код постраничной навигации не мой. Если будут варианты получше, предлагайте.
**UPD.**
Должно получиться такое:

```
<div class="post-wrapper">
    <p class="pubdate">pubdate</p>
    <p class="post-text">Text 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post-wrapper">
    <p class="pubdate">pubdate</p>
    <p class="post-text">Text 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post-wrapper">
    <p class="pubdate">pubdate</p>
    <p class="post-text">Text 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post-wrapper">
    <p class="pubdate">pubdate</p>
    <p class="post-text">Text 4</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post-wrapper">
    <p class="pubdate">pubdate</p>
    <p class="post-text">Text 5</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post-wrapper">
    <p class="pubdate">pubdate</p>
    <p class="post-text">AText 1</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post-wrapper">
    <p class="pubdate">pubdate</p>
    <p class="post-text">AText 2</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post-wrapper">
    <p class="pubdate">pubdate</p>
    <p class="post-text">AText 3</p>
  </div>
  <div class="post-wrapper">
    <p class="pubdate">pubdate</p>
    <p class="post-text">AText 4</p>
  </div>
```

Возможно, вас запутает класс post-text. Я специально сделал один, но можно его продублировать в стилях и назвать article-text. И применить его к последним 4 тегам p. 
Выводятся все 5 дивов с небольшим текстом(массив posts, text), затем выводятся все 4 дива со статьёй(массив articles, article). Но так же нужно, чтобы это всё вывелось с сортировкой по дате. То есть, сначала может статья AText 1 быть, потом простой текст Text 5, затем снова простой текст Text 4, а потом ещё одна статья AText 2 и т.д., с сортировкой по pubdate.

Comment: а что не так с сортировкой? Добавьте пример ожидаемого вывода в сам вопрос

Comment: @Grundy Прошу прощения, забыл об одной мелочи. Статья с датой и текст с датой - в разных блоках. То есть, статья в одном post-wrapper, небольшой текст - в другом. 
С сортировкой всё отлично вроде бы. Но я сомневаюсь, что я корректно сортирую. А так работает. Проблема только с выводом массива в два блока. Если я сделаю два разных блока, в одном вывод item.text, в другом - item.article, то оно выведется без "глобальной" сортировки. Или сначала отсортируются по дате все item.text, а потом item.article и так и выведутся. Я уже пробовал, и не стал писать об этом варианте.

Comment: я так и не понял: что именно должно получиться в итоге? добавьте в вопрос пример выходной разметки, которую вы ожидаете для приведенных данных